# How do I solve this stock span using stacks?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, position, stock

So the problem that I'm trying to solve is where you have an array of stock prices where each position is a different stock price. Now the problem is writing an algorithm to calculate the span of the stock which basically means each i position contains the number of previous stocks that were either less than or equal to the current stock. This is what I have right now:

```
public static int[] stockSpan(int[] stock) {
    int[] span = new int[stock.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < stock.length; i++) {
        int index = i - 1;
        span[i] = 1;
        while (index >= 0 && stock[index] <= stock[i]) {

            span[i] += span[index];
            index -= span[index];
        }
    }
    return span;
}
```

What I'm trying to do now is use stacks to try and improve the running time of this to O(n). The thing is I'm more used to using for loops and arrays to solve this problem so how do I implement stacks into this algorithm?

Comment: Is sorting the stock prices in ascending order what you want to do?

Comment: why do you think you do this with stacks? I don't think you could do it in `O(n)`. `O(n log n)` is possible however.

Comment: Ok let's say the array for the stock prices was 10 8 5 4 2 5 7 9 then the array for the stock span would be 1 1 1 1 1 4 5 8. Basically the second array is the times when the stocks before position i was less than or equal to the current position i. I also think it is possible to make one that is O(n) if you implement a sorting algorithm.

Comment: First off I just want to know how you can use stacks to make this work and then I'll see if I can implement a sorting algorithm to try and get the running time to O(n).

Comment: `calculate the span of the stock which basically means each i position contains the number of previous stocks that were either less than or equal to the current stock` In this case for your example `10 8 5 4 2 5 7 9` shouldn't the result be `1 1 1 1 1 3 4 7`?

Comment: `I also think it is possible to make one that is O(n) if you implement a sorting algorithm`. The sorting is `O(n log n)` so your algorithm would be at least `O(n log n)`. I still don't see why stacks could work.

Comment: 1 1 1 1 1 4 5 8 would be right because you're also counting the current value as well. So with the 6th position it would count 5 then 2 then 4 and then 5 making 4 i values that were less than or equal to the current value.

Comment: I see but actually it should be `1 1 1 1 1 4 5 7`.

Comment: Yes I missed that one. So how would I implement stacks with this algorithm. In the case of running times, there have been cases where someone has said that a certain running time isn't possible but then I implemented a sorting algorithm and that running time became possible.

Comment: Again I'm telling you that there is no reason to belief that you could do this with stacks. And why do you exactly want to use stacks? The `O(n log n)` I know uses different ideas.

Comment: Because it's said that stacks can be used to reduce the running time to O(n) so that's why I want to use stacks.

Comment: `it's said that stacks can be used to reduce the running time to O(n)` said where? btw use @svs in the beginning of your reply so I can see it.

Comment: Are the stock prizes in a fixed known range? If that is the case you may be able to use counting sort to do sorting in linear time

Comment: No but the first array (the stock prices array) is known.

Answer (score 1):

[Solution Source](https://youtu.be/g1USSZVWDsY?t=2629)

**Stock Span problem:** For a given array P of stock prices the stock span is the maximum number of consecutive days the price of the stock has been less than or equal to its price on day i. This can be solved efficiently using a stack.

```
 public static int[] computeSpan(int[] P) {
    int length = P.length;
    int[] S = new int[P.length];
    MyStack<Integer> myStack = new MyStack<>(length);
    int h = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        h = 0;
        while (!myStack.isEmpty()) {
            if (P[i] >= P[myStack.top()]) {
                myStack.pop();
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        h = myStack.isEmpty() ? -1 : myStack.top();
        S[i] = i - h;
        myStack.push(i);
    }
    return S;
}
```

Please go through the link for solution reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution :

```
public static Map<Integer, Integer> getStockSpan(int[] prices) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> stockSpan = new HashMap<>();
        Stack<Integer> span = new Stack<>();
        for (int price : prices) {
            int count = 1;
            while (!span.isEmpty() && price >= span.peek()) {
                count += stockSpan.get(span.pop());
            }
            span.push(price);
            stockSpan.put(price, count);
        }
        return stockSpan;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my code in C++ using stack library

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

void CalculateSpan(int a[],int n,int S[]){
    stack<int> st;
    //create the stack 
    int i;
    st.push(0); //pushed first element of ARRAY to stack 
    //as there is nothing to the left of initial element set its span as 1 to default
    S[0]=1;
    for(i=1;i<n;i++){
        //start looping from index 1
        //basically we are comparing initial element with all other element
        //now initially if top of stack is less than ith index of array then just pop
        while(!st.empty()&&a[st.top()]<=a[i])
          st.pop();
          if(st.empty())
           S[i]=i+1;
          else
          //to get span if ith index greater then top then just substract ith from top index and push the ith index
           S[i]=i-st.top();
           st.push(i);
    }
}

void printa(int arr[],int n){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<arr[i];
    }
}

int main()
{
  int a[10],S[10];
  int n,i;
  cout<<"Enter the size of the element you want";
  cin>>n;
  cout<<"\nEnter the number of elements you want\n";
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
      cin>>a[i];
  }
  CalculateSpan(a,n,S);
  printa(S,n);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

perform these operation n times :
1) two get the value u need to calculate
   res = i-R+1
   where i is current index and R is the index popped from stack

2) do following
   i) if stack is not empty and current element is >= to the element at top index then do following

while stack is not empty and current element is >= to the a[top]         do pop()

ii) push the current index to the stack and calculate the value

```
    int *a, *res;
    a = new int[n];
    res = new int[n];
    stack<int>S;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int top = i;
        if(!S.empty() && a[S.top()]<=a[i]) {
            while(!S.empty() && a[S.top()]<=a[i]){
                top = S.top();
                S.pop(); 
            }
            S.push(top);
        }
        S.push(i);
        res[i] = i-top+1; 
    }
```